# How to change the set value of a text field

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textinputfield

So I have TextFormField and it has a set value. However when I try to change the value of it by typing in the Feild, it just reverts to the specified value. This is my code:

```
TextFormField(
                onEditingComplete: () {

                  FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                  setState(() {
                    
                    // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO CHANGE ITS VALUE

                  });

                },
                
                controller: _titleController..text = newTask.title, //newTask IS AN OBJECT
                cursorHeight: 23.0,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  disabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: "Enter Text",
                  labelText: "Title",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I need to somehow set `_titleController.text` to the value that is in the field when `enter` or the tick button is clicked - but I cant just do `_titleController.text = _titleController.text;` for obvious reasons. Please help. Comment if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign the value of **newTask.title** to **_titleController.text**

```
controller: _titleController..text = newTask.title, //newTask IS AN OBJECT
```

Make it:

```
controller: _titleController
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   _titleController.text = newTask.title;
  }
.
.
.
.
.
//And in your TextFormField
controller: _titleController,
```